# Files in library project gives Permission denied error when accessing from main project

Tags: android, android-library

I am getting -

```
09-23 01:13:13.488: W/System.err(15728):    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.testapp.main/databases/MYContent: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
09-23 01:13:13.489: W/System.err(15728):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
09-23 01:13:13.489: W/System.err(15728):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
09-23 01:13:13.489: W/System.err(15728):    at com.testapp.main.MainFragmentActivity.backupDatabase(MainFragmentActivity.java:1411)
```

The exception only comes when the application is used as a library for main app.

**Working -**

```
testApp (data/data/com.testapp.main/databases/MYContent)
    \
     \
      RUN
```

**Not Working -**

```
testApp (data/data/com.testapp.main/databases/MYContent) (library)
    \
     \
      mainApp
       \
        \
         RUN
```

I know that the problem `open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)` is because -

Any other app can't access the file that is in different app.

But my app `testapp` is no different but a library which I am just accessing from main app `mainApp`.

How to access it ?

**MainFragmentActivity.java**

```
    String inFileName = "/data/data/com.testapp.main/databases/MYContent";
    File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile); //error here.
```

Comment: instead of hardcoding the path use `getReadableDatabase().getPath()` or `dbObject.getPath();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are hard-coding the path to this file. Use [getFileStreamPath()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFileStreamPath(java.lang.String)) or [getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()) to get the appropriate location (similarly, use the methods in Context when writing the files). This will ensure that the code works correctly no matter what app it is bundled into.